# The night of VS the night after

Tags: idioms

Let’s say you have a wedding on a Thursday. If someone says they booked a hotel for “**the night before and the night after the wedding**”, do you understand that to be Wed/Thu or Wed/Fri?
If the former, shouldn’t you instead say “**the night before and the night of**”?

Answer (score -1):

> "I booked a hotel for the night before, and the night *of* the wedding."

If the intention was to have booked the room for Wednesday and Thursday nights, then the above would be the appropriate description.

> "I booked a hotel for the night before, and the night *after* the wedding."

Explicitly as written, this would indicate that the person has booked a hotel room for Wednesday night, and Friday night.

Comment: Only if they specify they are spending the night *of* the wedding somewhere else would the night *after* make sense as you have it. If you just say *the night after*, without anything else, it would be assumed that you're talking about the night after the *event* of the wedding. If the wedding is at 5:00 p.m., then the night after *the wedding*, is still (without further context) ***that*** night.

Comment: I agree with @JasonBassford, the night after the wedding could be the next night that comes up after the wedding. If the wedding ends in the afternoon, the "night after" could be the "night of" the wedding.